# Calculating the inflection point of a cubic bezier curve?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, bezier

I have four points that make a cubic bezier curve:

```
P1 = (10, 5)
P2 = (9, 12)
P3 = (24, -2)
P4 = (25, 3)
```

Now I want to find the inflection point of this curve. I googled and/but everyone is referring to one site: http://www.caffeineowl.com/graphics/2d/vectorial/cubic-inflexion.html

Unfortunately the applets are not working and I simply fail to put it all together. Could someone please be so kind to show me how to calculate the inflection point of my curve?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on MBo's answer, `C(t) = X' * Y'' - X'' * Y' = 0` is pretty much the pseudocode you want already, because the first and second derivatives are really easy to calculate.

Following [this explanation of Bezier derivatives](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives), and a generic Bezier function with coordinates (x1,y1)...(x4,y4) we get:

```
fx(t) = x1 (1-t)³ + 3·x2·(1-t)²·t + 3·x3·(1-t)·t² + x4·t³
fx'(t) = a·(1-t)² + 2·b·(1-t)·t + c·t²
```

where a = 3(x2-x1), b = 3(x3-x2), and c = 3(x4-x3), and:

```
fx''(t) = u·(1-t) + v·t
```

where u = 2(b-a) and v = 2(c-b). And of course the same goes for the y component:

```
fy(t) = y1 (1-t)³ + 3·y2·(1-t)²·t + 3·y3·(1-t)·t² + y4·t³
fy'(t) = a'·(1-t)² + 2·b'·(1-t)·t + c'·t²
fy''(t) = u'·(1-t) + v'·t
```

where `a'` is the same as `a` but with `y` values, etc.

Working out the maths for `C(t) = fx'(t)·fy''(t) - fx''(t)·fy'(t)` is annoying, but that's why we own computers. If you own a raspberry pi, you own a license for Mathematica, so let's put that to use:

[image]

That's a massive formula, but finding the inflections for an "arbitrary" curve is a bit silly, because Bezier curves are invariant to linear affine transforms, so the the `t` value of the inflection point stays the same whether we check "the real curve" or whether we rotate/translate/scale the curve so that it has more convenient coordinates. Like translating it so that (x1,y1) ends up being (0,0), and (x4,y4) lies on the x-axis so that y4 is zero.

If we do that, then we get a vastly simpler formula:

[image]

How much simpler is this? well:

```
18 times:
  -     x3 * y2
  + 3 * x3 * y2 * t
  - 3 * x3 * y2 * t^2
  -     x4 * y2 * t
  + 2 * x4 * y2 * t^2
  +     x2 * y3
  - 3 * x2 * y3 * t
  + 3 * x2 * y3 * t^2
  -     x4 * y3 * t^2
```

Which, since we're programming, is a ton of cacheable values. Taking:

```
a = x3 * y2
b = x4 * y2
c = x2 * y3
d = x4 * y3
```

we can simplify `C(t)` as:

```
1/18 * C(t) = -a + 3at - 3at^2 - bt + 2bt^2 + c - 3ct + 3ct^2 - dt^2
= -3at^2 + 2bt^2 + 3ct^2 - dt^2 + 3at - bt - 3ct - a + c
= (-3a + 2b + 3c - d)t^2 + (3a - b - 3c)t + (c - a)
```

Putting that factor 18 back in, this is just a simple quadratic formula, for which we can find the roots using the quadratic root identity with more simple values:

```
v1 = (-3a + 2b + 3c - d) * 18
v2 = (3a - b - 3c) * 18
v3 = (c - a) * 18
```

And, provided `3a +d` *is not equal to* `2b+3c` (because there are no roots if that is the case), we get:

```
  sqr = sqrt(v2^2 - 4 * v1 * v3)
    d = 2 * v1
root1 =  (sqr - v2) / d
root2 = -(sqr + v2) / d
```

Throw away roots that don't fall in the Bezier interval [0,1], and what you're left with are the `t` values for which your original curve inflects.

> It's just that I am not able to put things together in a way so that I end up having some nice pseudo-code. That is also why I gave some points and coordinates. I'd like to see someone calculating this with real numbers

Especially on Stackoverflow, it's better not to be lazy up front and instead commit to probably having to learn a new thing.

Comment: I have put in Python, but I am getting wrong results. Is that still me missing something or is there some typo in there?? http://hastebin.com/osujiwagix.py

Comment: yes, obviously those inputs will fail. Reread the paragraph above "*If we do that, then we get a vastly simpler formula*", because the analysis you built your code on requires you to axis-align your curve first.

Comment: Now that I got it, things are obvious. Thank you, Mike!

Comment: what if bezier curve has 3 dimensions ?? how to calculate inflection point of 3d cubic bezier ??

Comment: Why so many question marks? One works just fine. Having said that: you'd be finding all points where the _planar_ curvature changes sign, something which is easily computed "for any given point" but is not something you can symbolically solve for the entire curve in a few steps, so you're left with numerical analysis (which in programming means: write a for loop to sample the curve, find transition pairs, and refine).

Answer (score 4):

For Bezier curve you have two parametric equations X(t) and Y(t).
To determine inflection point of parametric curve, you need to find where curve curvature ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions)) changes the sign. So you need to find the first and the second derivatives of above functions and solve equation:

```
C(t) = X' * Y'' - X'' * Y' = 0
```

*The first derivative is quadratic,  the second is linear, so equation is cubic for `t` and may have up to 3 solutions.*

**Edit:** Have read linked article, equation is simplified to quadratic one and may have up to 2 solutions.

If solution(s) exists in t range 0..1, you have also to check whether it is real inflection point - check that `C'(t) <> 0` at this t value.

Example: blue circles are inflection points (two catched)

[image]

Pieces of real code (Delphi)
Given:
P is array of control points
Cf is coefficients of Bezier in power basis

```
P, Cf: array[0..3] of TPoint

//calculate Bezier coefficients
Cf[3].x := p[3].x - 3 * p[2].x + 3 * p[1].x - p[0].x;
Cf[2].x := 3 * (p[0].x - 2 * p[1].x + p[2].x);
Cf[1].x := 3 * (p[1].x - p[0].x);
Cf[0].x := p[0].x;
//the same for Y

//find parameters of quadratic equation
// a*t^2 + b*t + c = 0
a := 3 * (cf[2].X *cf[3].Y - cf[2].Y *cf[3].X);
b := 3 * (cf[1].X *cf[3].Y - cf[1].Y *cf[3].X);
c := cf[1].X *cf[2].Y - cf[1].Y *cf[2].X;

//here solve quadratic equations, find t parameters
//don't forget a lot of special cases like a=0, D<0, D=0, t outside 0..1 range
Discriminant := b * b - 4 * a * c;
....
```

Comment: Are you familiar with parametric curve representation? Can you transform Bezier curve from Bernstein basis to polynomial basis representation?